# Tailing the Meteor Server Console

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-up

After deploying the Meteor app to a server, how can you tail the console output on the Meteor server? The app was deployed using `meteor-up` running on Meteor 0.7.

Answer (score 2):

How about this? Which is mentioned in the docs:

```
mup logs -f
```

Docs: https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up

Comment: Is there a way to do it if you are not using mup? we keep the process running using tmux.

Comment: What are the benefits of running meteor in tmux vs screen?

Comment: Unsure. But we are no longer using tmux. We opted for forever.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply ssh into the remote server, optionally use a utility like 'screen' if you want to keep a persistent shell going, and run:

```
tail -f /path/to/your/log
```

Depending on your deployment the log location will change. We also make use of a third party log service called PaperTrail which provides a handy way to search and view logs in near real time.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using the [new version](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx#), which I recommend, you do `mupx logs -f`